# Why does itunecconnect not accept my geoJSON file?

Tags: app-store-connect, geojson

My file is

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
                    [[[37.2732892, 55.9551567], [37.8780522, 55.9633486], [37.993164, 55.5512744], [37.1913337,55.5559836]]]
                    ]
}
```

This site shows than it is ok. http://geojsonlint.com/
However, itunesconnect does not accept. Please help

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: invalid file. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and last points of the polygon must be the same. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html

> Per the GeoJSON specification, every child polygon must represent a
>   closed region—that is, the first and last coordinate values must
>   always be identical. Therefore, you must specify at least four points
>   to define a triangular region, which is the simplest possible shape.
>   Of course, you use more points to define more complex polygons.

and the geojson spec http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#linestring

> A LinearRing is closed LineString with 4 or more positions. The first
>   and last positions are equivalent (they represent equivalent points).
>   Though a LinearRing is not explicitly represented as a GeoJSON
>   geometry type, it is referred to in the Polygon geometry type
>   definition.

Try this:

```
{
   "type":"MultiPolygon",
   "coordinates":[
      [
         [
            [
               37.2732892,
               55.9551567
            ],
            [
               37.8780522,
               55.9633486
            ],
            [
               37.993164,
               55.5512744
            ],
            [
               37.1913337,
               55.5559836
            ],
            [
               37.2732892,
               55.9551567
            ]
         ]
      ]
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a `FeatureCollection`:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [[[[37.2732892, 55.9551567], [37.8780522, 55.9633486], [37.993164, 55.5512744], [37.1913337, 55.5559836]]]]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```